# Spring REST - Post combinate JSON (multiple objects)

Tags: json, spring, rest, cloud, feign

I have four tables:

1. car

   - id
   - color
   - manufacturer
   - model
2. seat

   - id
   - name
   - id_car
3. tire

   - id
   - name
   - circlet
   - id_car
4. sound_player

   - id
   - name
   - id_car

I would like to know if using Spring REST, it is possible to write via POST a complete JSON, containing the objects of various models, without having to send the individual object of each model.

An example of a complete JSON would be as follows:

```
{
    "color": "white",
    "manufacturer": "toyota",
    "model": "corolla",
    "seat": {
        "name": "Recaro",
    },
    "tire": {
        "name": "Recaro",
        "circlet": "18",
    }, 
    "soundPlayer": {
        "name": "Sony DHC-5000",
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create some DTO which will contain all models you need
with all parameters

You can read about dto pattern by this link:

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/design_pattern/transfer_object_pattern.htm

In you case you can create :

```
@Getter
@Setter
public class CarDto{
 private String color;
 private String manufacturer;
 private String model;
 private SeatDto seat;
 private TireDto tire;
 private SoundPlayerDto soundPlayer;
}

@Getter
@Setter
public class SeatDto {
 private String name;
}

@Getter
@Setter
public class TireDto{
  private String name;
  private String circlet
}

@Getter
@Setter
public class SoundPlayerDto{
  private String name;
  private String circlet
}
```

And you can pass your request as you described:

```
@RequestBody  CarDto carDto;
```

Then you can write your own converters from dto to you real entities and work with them

@Getter and @Setter its lombok annotation you can read about them from following link:

https://projectlombok.org/features/GetterSetter